# Legend for map is not coming up right

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, legend

I am drawing the map of US showing number of restaurants in each state and not getting the correct legend. The color of each state depends on the range of restaurants in that state. This code is entirely reproducible.

```
library(ggplot2)

windowsFonts(Arial=windowsFont("TT Arial"))

colorsnew <- c("#C6D7A9","#9DAED9","#C6D7A9","#4A77BB","#9DAED9","#9DAED9","#C7C6C5","#C7C6C5","#4A77BB","#7aad42","#C7C6C5",
  "#4A77BB","#9DAED9","#C6D7A9","#C6D7A9","#C6D7A9","#C6D7A9","#C7C6C5","#9DAED9","#7aad42","#7aad42","#9DAED9","#C6D7A9","#9DAED9",
  "#C7C6C5","#C7C6C5","#C6D7A9","#C7C6C5","#7aad42","#C7C6C5","#4A77BB","#7aad42","#C7C6C5","#7aad42","#C6D7A9","#9DAED9","#4A77BB",
  "#C7C6C5","#9DAED9","#C7C6C5","#9DAED9","#4A77BB","#C6D7A9","#C7C6C5","#9DAED9","#9DAED9","#C7C6C5","#9DAED9","#C7C6C5")
color_legend <- c("0-5000", "5000-10000","10000-20000","20000-30000","30000+")

usa_map <- map_data("state")
plotObj <- ggplot(usa_map, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))
plotObj <- plotObj  + geom_polygon(data=usa_map, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=region), colour ="white")

plotObj <- plotObj +  scale_fill_manual(values=as.character(colorsnew), label=color_legend)
plotObj <- plotObj +  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                            axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                            legend.text = element_text(family = "Arial"), legend.position = "top",
                            legend.title = element_text(family = "Arial", size = rel(1)),
                            strip.text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
                            panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
plotObj <- plotObj + labs(title="Distribution of Restaurants across states in U.S. and Canada")

print(plotObj)
```

My problem is that the legend should show each color once that I can label according to the color_legend vector. However, when I set `legend.position = "top"`,it is showing me the color for all the 49 states. How can I set the legend so that each color shows only once with its appropriate labels? I have tried using geom_map, but it gave me weird errors. Thanks!

Comment: `geom_map` might be useful.

Comment: please provide reproducible data...

Comment: @Richard Telford: I have tried geom_map, but could not get the right colors for each state. The colors also looked different than the actual. I now have reproducible data and code in my question. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: rather than giving a vector of colours, you should give the vector of the number of restaurants, and let ggplot map this to colour. You can use scale_fill_continuous to control the mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label for the fill colors manually:

```
plotObj <- plotObj +  scale_fill_manual(
                              values=as.character(unique(colorsnew),
                              labels=color_legend
                                        )
```

I couldn't test it in your scenario, so I'm not sure if it works. I assume you also have to set the legend.position = "top" or comment this point out.

EDIT:
Your legend only shows only the first 5 states, because you only provide 5 labels to scale_fill_manual. I missed that in your example before you provided the whole column map.df$colors_new, which I assume are 49 values, so 44 values are missing.

To solve this try to put unique around your vector(see above). That will reduce the column to the 5 single color values. Be aware that the order of the colors is correct. Alternatively you just build a vector with the 5 color values in the correct order.

```
colorsnew <- c("#C6D7A9","#9DAED9","#4A77BB","#C7C6C5","#7aad42")
```

I hope it works this time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this out. The legend is placed for the first 5 states and the other states show NA.